# Bug da aceitação desfeita

Tags: bug

Respondi a pergunta e o AP marcou como aceita. Percebi que não houve nenhuma mudança na minha reputação e fui consultar a aba "Reputação" e pareceu que a resposta foi aceita e depois desfeita, mas na página da pergunta a resposta continua como marcada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há poucos instantes o site exibia uma mensagem de que estava havendo um problema técnico (aquelas mensagens, tipo: "*estamos com problemas técnicos e estamos correndo para resolver etc.*")... Talvez esse erro tenha bugado a marcação da resposta ou o bônus à minha reputação.

Pergunta em questão: [Qual erro estou cometendo quando coloco o terceiro item "endereco" no codigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/302065/8063)

### Edit

Pedi para o AP desmarcar e marcar novamente, mas mesmo assim aparece como na imagem acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal, para fechar a pergunta, vou responder de forma bem sucinta:

Enviei um email pro suporte do SO e recebi uma resposta dizendo que o AP havia desfeito a aceitação e depois aceitado. O problema é que a reputação não foi acrescentada. Acho que eles olharam muito superficialmente o caso, da forma da imagem na pergunta. Enfim, caso encerrado. Não tem problema se eu não ganhei os `+15`, o que importa é que o AP foi ajudado, e esse é o meu foco primário (o secundário é ganhar os pontos, mas se não deu, não há problema).

Comment: coloquei +1 lá pra acrescentar seus pontos =]

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado!! :)